# If $K$ and $L$ are nth syzygies modules for $M$ then $K\sim L$

Tags: homological-algebra, dimension-theory-analysis

If $K$ and $L$ are nth syzygies modules for $M$ then $K\sim L$

$K\sim L$ means there exists P and Q are projective modules such that $K\oplus Q=L\oplus P$

I try to use induction so it suffices to show that if $K$ and $L$ are the first syzygies module for $M$ and $N$ where $M\sim N$ then $K\sim L$ but I got stuck there.

Comment: Google for Schanuel´s lemma.

Comment: I know schanuel's lemma however, is it the same? I got stuck because I do not know how to use $M\sim N$ for linking $L$ and $K$ from $ M\oplus P=N\oplus Q$

Comment: If $0\to K\to P\to M\to 0$ is exact and has middle term projective and $P'$ is projective, then you can easily construct $0\to K\to P\oplus P'\to M\oplus P'\to 0$ exact with middle term projective.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.

Comment: **Please** write a complete answer, so that the question does not remain unanswered.